# Что означает конструкция с угловыми скобками <> при определении и использовании классов и интерфейсов?

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

В текстах программ на Java при определении и использовании классов и интерфейсов часто встречаются конструкции вида `class SomeClass<T> {...}` или `SomeClass<String> myObj = new SomeClass<String>` или ещё что-то в этом роде. Что это такое и зачем?

Comment: почитайте про [generic types в java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), на русском не знаю где лучше, просто как пример [одну ссылку оставлю](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это Generic types, который позволят потом определять тип.

```
public class GenericsType<T> {

private T t;

public T get(){
    return this.t;
}

public void set(T t1){
    this.t=t1;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    GenericsType<String> type = new GenericsType<>();
    type.set("Pankaj"); //valid

    GenericsType type1 = new GenericsType(); //raw type
    type1.set("Pankaj"); //valid
    type1.set(10); //valid and autoboxing support
}
}
```

Другой пример:

```
public interface MyInyerface<E> {
    void print(E e);
}

public class MyClass implements MyInyerface<String> {
    @Override
    public void print(String s) {

    }


    class MyClassInteger implements  MyInyerface<Integer>{

        @Override
        public void print(Integer integer) {

        }
    }
}
```

Вот тут указав тип данных, методы могут принимать только этот тип. Это нужно, если вам нужно на вход только определенный тип, и в случае, если передали другой тип, вы получите ошибку не во время компиляции, а во время анализа кода.

Подробнее можно почитать  [Тут](http://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-example-method-class-interface) и [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html)
и вот [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) еще

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, на Generic types, т.к. дженерики могут быть не только у интерфейса

Comment: Вы показали <T>, а как насчет вопроса топикстартера про <E> ?

Comment: @Kromster а какая разница `<T>` или `<E>` )?

Comment: Я например с Java незнаком. Скажите, есть разница между <T> или <E> ?

Comment: @Kromster: С точки зрения использования никакой, это же просто название типа-параметра. Всё равно что `void f(int x)` и `void f(int y)`, отличаются только именем параметра.

Comment: @VladD на это и обращаю внимание, что было бы хорошо осветить этот момент в ответе. Иначе получается ТС спрашивает про Е, а ему почему-то про Т отвечают.

Answer (score 1):

То, о чём вы говорите -- это определение и/или использование так называемых "обобщенных" или "параметризуемых" типов (Generalized types, Generics). Это механизм, который позволяет определить класс или интерфейс, экземпляры которого **могут работать с данными разных типов**, при этом **конкретный тип** этих данных указывается **при использовании** такого обобщенного типа, напр. при определении переменной или параметра метода. Типичный пример использования таких классов -

```
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); // список строк
    ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // список чисел
    stringList.add("123");   // OK
    stringList.add(123);     // Ошибка! 
    intList.add("123");   // Ошибка! 
    intList.add(123);     // OK
```

При определении такого типа в его заголовке и в его теле используется произвольный идентификатор для указания типа-параметра - того типа, с которым будет работать конкретный экземпляр определяемого класса или интерфейса (в теле используется так, как будто это уже известный тип, для обозначения типов переменных и т. п.):

```
class SomeClass < T > {
...
    private T value;
    public T getValue() { ... }
}
```

При использовании такого типа в качестве параметра указывается конкретный тип, с которым должен работать экземпляр этого обобщенного типа:

```
    SomeClass< Integer > intInstance = new SomeClass< Integer >();
    SomeClass< ArrayList > listInstance = new SomeClass< ArrayList>();
    ....
    int i = intInstance.getValue(); // OK
    int j = listInstance.getValue(); // Error!!!
    ArrayList list = listInstance.getValue(); // OK
```

Использование обобщенных типов даёт кучу преимуществ:

1. Меньше писанины (генерализованный класс нужно описать только один раз);
2. Выше надежность (нельзя всунуть число в список, который должен содержать строки);
3. Выше читабельность (сразу видно, что ArrayList< String> - это для строк)

Это только общее представление, там ещё есть ряд нюансов (ограничения типов, шаблоны), но про эти подробности лучше почитать в книжках.

Answer (score 0):

Это означает параметризированный тип. Конкретно <> оператор (к слову, называется diamond, или же алмазный оператор), который говорит компилятору, какой тип к нему должен придти - все остальные типы он станет отвергать еще на этапе семантической проверки кода.

В этот оператор(<>) можно помещать лишь оболочки примитивов или же классы(прим. `List<int> list = new ArrayList<>();` не покатит).

Насчет `<E>` - честно говоря я не помню, что означает (этот момент лучше уточните по ссылкам в ответе @Senior Automator).

Так же можно проверять, наследуется ли тип от другого типа `<? extends SomeClass>`, и т.д.

Comment: `<E>` - это совсем не то же самое что и `<T>` Это два разных идентификатора!

Comment: @PavelMayorov я же сказал, что точно не припомню, указал в ответе.

Comment: Ну так исправьте ответ-то.